# display collentionview from result of collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I have 2 collection views within 1 view controller.  I want the 2nd collection view to display its contents based on the selection of an item in the first collectionview.  Ive got it all working to the point where it gets the data to display but i think because the viewcontroller isn't reloading it isn't displaying the data (cell images, descriptions ect).  how can i force refresh the view or is there a better way or showing the result in the 2nd collectionview?

full code for the class is below:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

private let reuseIdentifierPart = "CellPart"
private let reuseIdentifierPiece = "CellPiece"

class JourneyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    // passed packName from PackViewController
    var selectedPack: String!
    var selectedPart: String!

    @IBOutlet var collectionViewPart: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var collectionViewPiece: UICollectionView!

    struct partStruct {
        var partName : String
        var partDescription : String
        var partTitle : String
        var partImage : PFFile
        var partID: String
    }

    struct pieceStruct {
        var pieceName : String
        //var pieceDescription : String
        //var pieceTitle : String
        var pieceImage : PFFile
    }

    var partArray = [partStruct]()
    var pieceArray = [pieceStruct]()

    var refreshView: UIViewController!


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // if selected pack not nil
        //--------------------------------------------- PART DISPLAY IN COLLECTION ----
        if let partsToDisplay = selectedPack {
            let partQuery = PFQuery(className: "Part")
                //have to create PFObject from selectedPack
                partQuery.whereKey("fromPack", equalTo: PFObject(outDataWithClassName: "Pack", objectId: selectedPack))
                partQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objectsArray, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                    } else if let parts = objectsArray {
                        for object in parts {

                            let arrayName = object.object(forKey: "partName") as! String
                            let arrayDescription = object.object(forKey: "partDescription") as! String
                            let arrayTitle = object.object(forKey: "partTitle") as! String
                            let arrayImage = object.object(forKey: "partImage") as! PFFile
                            //let arrayPoint = object.object(forKey: "fromPack") as! String
                            let arrayID = object.objectId as String!
                            self.partArray.append(partStruct(partName: arrayName, partDescription: arrayDescription, partTitle: arrayTitle, partImage: arrayImage, partID: arrayID!))
                        }
                        self.partArray = self.partArray.sorted{ $0.partName < $1.partName }
                        self.collectionViewPart?.reloadData()
                    }
                })
        }

    }//viewwillappear

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewPart {
            //--------------------------------------------- PIECE DISPLAY IN COLLECTION ----
            print("I selected an item in the Parts stack")
            selectedPart = self.partArray[indexPath.item].partID
            print("i selected item \(selectedPart)")

            if let piecesToDisplay = selectedPart {
                let pieceQuery = PFQuery(className: "Piece")
                //have to create PFObject from selectedPack
                pieceQuery.whereKey("fromPart", equalTo: PFObject(outDataWithClassName: "Part", objectId: selectedPart))
                pieceQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objectsArray, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                    } else if let pieces = objectsArray {
                        print(objectsArray?.count)
                        for object in pieces {

                            let arrayName = object.object(forKey: "pieceName") as! String
                            let arrayImage = object.object(forKey: "pieceImage") as! PFFile

                            self.pieceArray.append(pieceStruct(pieceName: arrayName, pieceImage: arrayImage))
                        }
                        self.pieceArray = self.pieceArray.sorted{ $0.pieceName < $1.pieceName }
                        self.collectionViewPiece?.reloadData()
                    }
                })

            } else {
                // this is for selecting somehitng in the vertical stack
                print("WERE GOING TO GO TO THE NEXT SCREEN AND PLAY THE SOUND FILE")

            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewPart {

            //pass this to the piece query when selected
            let selectedPart = self.partArray[indexPath.item].partName
            //--------------------------------------------- PART HOW TO DISPLAY EACH ITEM ----

            let cellPart: PartCollectionViewCell = collectionViewPart.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierPart, for: indexPath) as! PartCollectionViewCell

            //cellPart.labelCell.text = self.packArray[indexPath.item].packDescription
            //cellPart.labelCell.textColor = MyFunctions.UIColorFromHEX(hexValue: 0x0c1537)
            cellPart.imageCellPart.file = self.partArray[indexPath.item].partImage

            cellPart.imageCellPart.loadInBackground()

            cellPart.imageCellPart.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cellPart.imageCellPart.layer.cornerRadius = cellPart.imageCellPart.frame.height/2
            cellPart.imageCellPart.layer.borderWidth = 3
            cellPart.imageCellPart.layer.borderColor = MyFunctions.UIColorFromHEX(hexValue: 0x62aca2).cgColor

            return cellPart

        } else {
            //--------------------------------------------- PIECE HOW TO DISPLAY EACH ITEM ----

            let cellPiece: PieceCollectionViewCell = collectionViewPiece.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierPiece, for: indexPath) as! PieceCollectionViewCell

            //cellPiece.labelCell.text = self.packArray[indexPath.item].packDescription
            //cellPiece.labelCell.textColor = MyFunctions.UIColorFromHEX(hexValue: 0x0c1537)
            cellPiece.imageCellPiece.file = self.pieceArray[indexPath.item].pieceImage

            cellPiece.imageCellPiece.loadInBackground()

            cellPiece.imageCellPiece.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cellPiece.imageCellPiece.layer.cornerRadius = cellPiece.imageCellPiece.frame.height/2
            cellPiece.imageCellPiece.layer.borderWidth = 3
            cellPiece.imageCellPiece.layer.borderColor = MyFunctions.UIColorFromHEX(hexValue: 0x62aca2).cgColor

            return cellPiece
        }

    }
    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewPart {
            return self.partArray.count
        } else {
            return self.pieceArray.count
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


}//class
```

Comment: first of all assign delegate to self, and write the result.

Answer (score 0):

`self.collectionViewPiece?.reloadData()` should happen on main thread, because all the UI updates have to be done on main thread. Do it this way

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.collectionViewPiece?.reloadData()
        })
```

Have the above code in `didSelectItemAt` instead of just `self.collectionViewPiece?.reloadData()`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == self.collectionViewPart {
        //--------------------------------------------- PIECE DISPLAY IN COLLECTION ----
        print("I selected an item in the Parts stack")
        selectedPart = self.partArray[indexPath.item].partID
        print("i selected item \(selectedPart)")

        if let piecesToDisplay = selectedPart {
            let pieceQuery = PFQuery(className: "Piece")
            //have to create PFObject from selectedPack
            pieceQuery.whereKey("fromPart", equalTo: PFObject(outDataWithClassName: "Part", objectId: selectedPart))
            pieceQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objectsArray, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                } else if let pieces = objectsArray {
                    print(objectsArray?.count)
                    for object in pieces {

                        let arrayName = object.object(forKey: "pieceName") as! String
                        let arrayImage = object.object(forKey: "pieceImage") as! PFFile

                        self.pieceArray.append(pieceStruct(pieceName: arrayName, pieceImage: arrayImage))
                    }
                    self.pieceArray = self.pieceArray.sorted{ $0.pieceName < $1.pieceName }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.collectionViewPiece?.reloadData()
        })
                }
            })

        } else {
            // this is for selecting somehitng in the vertical stack
            print("WERE GOING TO GO TO THE NEXT SCREEN AND PLAY THE SOUND FILE")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im a bit of noob with this so am unclear what you mean by main thread?  This does not work from inside the class and not allowed above the class

Comment: same result unfortunately.  Ill go back through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please execute this from your main thread.

```
  self.collectionViewPiece?.reloadData()
  self.collectionViewPiece?.layoutIfNeeded();
```

Comment: unfortunately did not produce a different result

Comment: (1) I'm assuming you have enabled the 'User Interaction Enabled'. (2) Also, do you see the elements (debugging/log) after the sort ? `self.partArray = self.partArray.sorted{ $0.partName < $1.partName }`

Comment: yeah interaction enabled and both arrays show correctly

Comment: Ok. In your `cellForItemAt` implementation, I'm assuming imageCellPart & imageCellPiece are not null at the point of you setting values to them. Also, i'm assuming you have the right constraints, display values set on `imageCellPart & imageCellPiece` (UIImageViews i suppose) on storyboard, with the specific custom classnames mapped on those cells.

Comment: yeah I've been back through and recreated all the outlets and links to classes.  there is something wrong with the display however.  it does not even display a place holder image in the collectionViewPiece.. maybe because it is a pffileview and not uiimageview

Comment: If your collectionview works with a `UIImageView` and not with custom `pffileview`, then your issue is at custom view definition and rendering - not with reloading uicollectionview.

Comment: both are running off PFFileview and the partcollectionview works fine.  stumped

Answer (score 0):

im not sure why, considering i had set both datasource and delegate within the storyboard however this fixed the problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionViewPart.delegate = self
    collectionViewPiece.delegate = self
    collectionViewPart.dataSource = self
    collectionViewPiece.dataSource = self
}
```